# How to delay loading a shared library in android

Tags: android, module, dependencies, kernel, shared-libraries

I am working on android where I faced a issue.
Let me explain my issue: In kernel I am getting a probe defer for my module and it is continuing with the android boot.
After few seconds my kernel  module probed again and its loaded perfect.
So the problem here is, one module from the android is trying to access the node which is created by my module.
How can I delay that module from loading.

For example: android's tinyhal library loading before my codec get registered with the kernel. 
And I want to delay the tinyhal to load little bit late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any shared library load is triggered by a process. So, you should ask *how to delay a process start* instead of *delay loading shared library*.

Try to look into your init script and ensure you have proper order for your services.